# Karma compiled element is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a simple directive with a templateUrl statement, I'm using ng-html2js to load the template. I compiled the element and call the `$digest` method, but the element is empty or its `html()` is `''`.

This is the test:

```
var scope, element;

    beforeEach(module('mainApp'));
    beforeEach(module('templates/about.html'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        element = angular.element('<about-modal></about-modal>');

        scope = $rootScope;
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('About widget is loaded', function () {
        expect(element.html()).toEqual('<some html>');
    });
```

It is like the element is not digested or populated. Has the same status before is compiled and digested.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was my fault.

I thought that loading a template as a module was enough to compile the element of the directive.

I made something like this to compile the template.

```
aboutTemplate = $templateCache.get('templates/about.html');
scope = $rootScope;
scope.appVersion = '2.0.0.1';
ele=$compile(aboutTemplate)(scope);
$rootScope.$digest();
```

This works, and now I am able to get the compiled directive, the template, in this case.

Thanks.